# How to/Can I dual boot Ubuntu on my system

Tags: windows-8

So I have a Windows 8.1 64bit system, that uses BIOS instead of UEFI, when I mounted Ubuntu 12.04 to my thumb drive and tried to boot from a device in the advanced startup options I noticed there was no "boot using device" option. So the question is how would I go about dual booting Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 8.1?

Comment: You want to look for boot device options in the BIOS, not Windows 8's startup options.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the priorities of bootable devices in your bios. Your Usb port should be indicated there, so bring it to the top of the list so your usb drive is detected first